# Scrivener: Play gifs?

Tags: scrivener

So I have a bunch of gifs saved in my Research folder, but unfortunately, when I click on them, they don't play - I have to open them in an external editor to view them. Is there a way to make them play directly inside of Scrivener?

Comment: The answer to the question is at the end of the [linked page](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10255&p=80079&hilit=animated+gif#p80079). I personally find Scrivener staff very responsive and friendly, and recommend asking them directly.

Comment: @Lew Isn't that different though? My question was aimed towards just viewing the gif when I import it as a standalone file in the Research folder, not when it's embedded in a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on the [comment from Lew](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/27010/scrivener-play-gifs#comment39790_27010) from [this page](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10255&p=80079&hilit=animated+gif#p80079): Scrivener does not allow you to play gifs directly, neither in your research folder, nor when embedded in a page.

I've looked through a few sites and discussions such as [this one](https://www.kboards.com/index.php?topic=166759.0) or [this one](http://gwenhernandez.com/2013/05/28/tech-tuesday-inserting-images-in-scrivener/) or [this one](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=24748) - but none of them describe your scenario and there is no mention of this being possible. Funny thing: your question here pops up first in Google for me when I search for "scrivener gif". There doesn't seem to be a lot of interest in the subject and no available documentation that would indicate something like this, which is why I conclude that the answer to your question "Is there a way to make them play directly inside of Scrivener?" is simply "No", no matter where you want to play the gif exactly in scrivener.

Comment: That's a shame... at least I have an answer to pick now.